Custom mat-error directive not working with Angular 18 zoneless
I have a generic mat-error directive that I've been using to show form errors.
@Component({
  selector: '[app-field-error]',
  templateUrl: './field-error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./field-error.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  standalone: true
})
export class FieldErrorComponent {

  field = input.required<AbstractControl<any, any>>();
  fieldName = input.required<string>();

}

And I show the errors on html side accordingly:
<span *ngIf="field().hasError('email')">
  Invalid email address.
</span>

Sample usage:
<mat-error app-field-error [field]="contactForm.get('name')" fieldName="Contact Name"/>

After trying zoneless with Angular18, this directive stopped working. I've migrated other components successfully using async pipes and signals accordingly, but in this case I am not sure how this component will get the input updates so that it can show the error messages.

I was able to make this work by subscribing to field statusChanges and calling ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck. Here is the code:
export class FieldErrorComponent implements OnInit {

 field = input.required<AbstractControl<any, any>>();
 fieldName = input.required<string>();

 constructor(
   private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
 ) {
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.field().statusChanges
     .pipe(
       tap(() => {
         this.cdr.markForCheck();
       })
     )
     .subscribe();
 }

}

